# How could a creature/species evolve erogenous zones in areas not usually sex-related?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, sex

For example, a half-cat half-human hybrid might have a zone partway down their tail, or a human might have one in an unusual place e.g. their scalp, shoulders, whatever.

I've seen this used in fiction before, but can't think of any way in which it could really be justified by ordinary biological/ecological circumstances (i.e. evolution).

Comment: Considering that we don't know which are "normal" erogenous zones (they vary among humans, and we ignore which are for all the other animals), can you better define the "unusual"? Maybe you mean "peculiar"?

Comment: Many humans have erogenous zones in their ears, which seems pretty "unusual" to me. It's just that we're used to it.

Comment: Conditioning can explain unusual erogenous zones. If you have your scalp rubbed while being aroused, eventually only the scalp rubbing may cause arousal.

Comment: Evolution doesn't justify anything. The development of organs, anatomical features, and, even, unusual erogenous zones can be *understood* as arising by evolution. You might clarify whether, by what, you are calling erogenous zones have genitalia. Your examples could be parts of anatomy which are sensitive to the touch and when stimulated this is pleasurable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erogenous zones *usually* are sex related, but that's *not* a evolutionary necessity. In mammal females (not just human ones) females breast erogenous zone is there because it favors breast-feeding (much after the sex act ;) ).

In cats there's a reflex to remain still if grabbed by the neck; this evolved to help mothers to carry their litter without having them wriggle out of reach. This is also largely exploited by males while coupling. I don't know if this can be called "erogenous zone" as it has nothing to do with sexual arousing (female cats do not need to be aroused by a male).

As You see definition is rather vague and theres the normal evolutionary tendency to "reuse" patterns for different purposes.
All You need to do, to justify a "peculiar" erogenous zone is to find a reason because (in certain conditions) stimulation of that zone is connected to something useful for survival of self or children. A bit of ingenuity could suggest (for example) an erogenous zone on the tip of the tail to favor being followed by children in a queue each holding preceding tail in mouth (like elephants in a circus).

Answer (score 0):

Normally when a male has to compete with others for the female, it has to prove his fitness level to breed. (Peacock tail, etc.).

If during the mating ritual, preceeding the factual mating, the ability of reaching a given erogenous zone can be the consequence of a high level fitness, than it would be totally justified from evolution.

E.g. imagine a bunch of male snakes competing for fecondate a single female. The female opens her orifice only after uninterrupted stimulation of a sensitive spot. To achieve that the fit male would have to be strong enough to keep away all other competitors while entangled to the female.

Comment: On the other hand, this instinctive fitness competition can go awry. Imagine a bunch of male humans competing to see how fast they could get their mom's old Civic or Camry to go... not realizing that the females could care less.